# Jquery find operations on dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create dynamic html content (table rows). td elements have class assigned to it depending on the row.

I want to perform multiple find element by class and perform .text() and style operations and then append final html to the table body.

I tried this and does not work. Please help.

```
            function processrow(html){

                    $(html).find(".item1").text('Closed');
                    $(html).find(".item5").css('background-color', '#66a666');

                    return html;
            }
```

example value passed to function

```
    <tr><td>row1</td><td class="item1"></td></tr>
```

Need it return

```
    <tr><td>row1</td><td class="item1">Closed</td></tr>
```

Added fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6mnLwg0o/2/

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: Hint: You pass a *string* to your function, strings are immutable, you don't do any assignments.

Comment: added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6mnLwg0o/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the jQuery object with the source by doing $(html), then make the changes to the inner elements with find().  In the example below I am appending the updated html to a test div so that you can see the result.

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var src = processrow('<table><tr><td class="item5">row1</td><td class="item1"></td></tr></table>');
src.appendTo($('#test'));

function processrow(html) {

    var obj = $(html);
    obj.find(".item1").text('Closed');
    obj.find(".item5").css('background-color', '#66a666');

    return obj;
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/td00gssw/

Answer (score 0):

When you say `$(html)` it creates a dom structure based on the `html` which is then modified. Change done in the dom after that will not get reflected in the source html, so to get the modified html you need to get the html from the dom objects.

```
function processrow(html) {
    var $div = $('<div />', {
        html: html
    });
    $div.find(".item1").text('Closed');
    $div.find(".item5").css('background-color', '#66a666');

    return $div.html();
}
```